# What is the UsersConnectionRepository for in Spring Social Facebook?

Tags: facebook, spring, facebook-graph-api, spring-security, spring-social

I'm following the directions here and elsewhere:
https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-social/wiki/Quick-Start

Why do we need to specify a dataSource and UsersConnectionRepository to use Spring Social Facebook? What gets written to our database? Am I supposed to create special tables or modify my Users table?

Comment: Well it's 2018 and the docs still don't quite explain what to do with this. Especially since there is also a `UserConnection` table I do not understand. Is there a chance you can tell me if I need to consider anything in particular regarding that table and repository respectively?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep from the docs ~ For convenience is bootstrapping the schema from a running application, this schema definition is available in the spring-social-core module as a resource at the path /org/springframework/social/connect/jdbc/JdbcUsersConnectionRepository.sql.

From here
http://static.springsource.org/spring-social/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/serviceprovider.html

You might want to take a look at the sample apps [here](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-social-samples/tree/master/spring-social-quickstart)